# Measure the "actual" number of dimentions in a multivariate distribution

Tags: correlation, multivariate-distribution, dimensions

Consider a 3D multivariate normal distribution $x\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ where
$$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}1 &1 &0 \\ 1&1&0 \\ 0 &0& 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are fully correlated, one could say that this is actually a "2 dimensions" distribution.

We can also imagine an intermediate case with:
$$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0.8 &0 \\ 0.8 &1 & 0 \\ 0 &0  & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

that could actually be a "2.2 dimentions" distribution.

Is there a mathematical tool to represent this idea?

Comment: Your second example would be a full rank multivariate normal related to 3D ellipsoid or spheroid shells rather than the spherical shells of uncorrelated standard multivariate normals or the 2D ellipses of the first example: the partial correlation does not affect the dimension

Comment: Best way to think about it is in terms of the eigenvalues of the matrix. In your first case there are only two non-zero eigenvalues (2,1,0). In the second case all 3 eigenvalues are nonzero, but the smallest one is quite small (1.8,1,.2).

Comment: The rank of the covariance matrix would do in the case of a Normal distribution.

Comment: There are *many* different ways to define the "dimension" of a closed subset of $\mathbb R^d,$ such as the support of a probability distribution: Hausdorff, fractal, algebraic, vector space, *etc.*   Which concept do you have in mind?  For instance, would you view a Poisson distribution as being zero-dimensional (the dimension of its support indeed is zero according to all accounts) or one-dimensional (because its support spans a one-dimensional vector space)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **theoretical** covariance matrix $\Sigma$, the rank tells you the number of dimensions. Whether you consider some of these dimensions insignificant from a substantive point of view is a substantive, not a statistical question.

If you have an **empirical** rather than theoretical covariance matrix $\hat\Sigma$, you could apply exploratory factor analysis (EFA). It is a technique for determining the underlying dimension of a group of variables each of which is supposedly generated as a linear combination of a smaller number of latent common factors plus an idiosyncratic factor (an error term, if you will). The way the number of dimensions is determined in EFA is a bit subjective, though.

Comment: There are a lot of methods for determining the dimensions of an empirical covariance matrix. The question comes up a lot in various big-data applications when applying a correction for multiple comparisons. For example in human genetics the standard alpha threshold is equivalent to a bonferroni correction for 1 million comparisons, despite most studies performing several million tests. This is because, with the high degree of correlations across the genome, it's estimated that there are only ~ 1 million independent sources of variance.